# mongodb index usage depends on notation

Tags: mongodb, indexing

Saying I have compound `_id` on collection A:

```
{
    _id:{
       orgUnit:Int64
       ...
    }
}
```

Querying such shows that index is used:

```
db.A.find({_id:{orgUnit:1039}}).explain()
```

...

```
    "indexBounds" : {
            "start" : {
                    "_id" : {
                            "orgUnit" : 1039
                    }
            },
            "end" : {
                    "_id" : {
                            "orgUnit" : 1039
                    }
            }
```

But when I changing query to "dot notation" shows that query became plain.

```
db.A.find({"_id.orgUnit":1039}).explain()
...
"indexBounds" : {

},
```

What is wrong with dot notation? And the main: How to leverage indexing to allow me find by `"_id.orgUnit"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to create a separate index on `'_id.orgUnit'` to efficiently query on that field using dot notation.

```js
db.A.ensureIndex({'_id.orgUnit': 1})
```

Comment: +1, But mongo site explicitly declares: "given the index { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 } both { a: 1 } and { a: 1, b: 1 } are prefixes of the index" - so orgUnit as first part of _id is already indexed.

Comment: @Dewfy That's true, but I don't think that's the case you have here unless you've already created as separate compound index that specifically references `_id.orgUnit`. The standard index on `_id` isn't a compound index, it's a sub-document index which isn't as flexible.

Answer (score 2):

These two queries mean two different things.

First one is like: "find me documents whose `_id` is exactly an object `{orgUnit: 1039}`".
Second one is like: "find me documents whose `_id` is an object with `orgUnit` property equal to 1039".

So the second query is weaker and will also match documents like `{_id: {foo: "bar", orgUnit: 1039}}` while the first query will not. Mongo cannot use index on `_id` to perform the second query.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have provided some edits to make my questions useful - "How to leverage indexing to allow me find by _id.orgUnit"